Is 男 ‘man’ or ‘male’?
I’ve looked at multiple dictionaries and websites and received both as an answer. Is both correct or is one answer more correct?

Is there something about it meaning both that is giving you trouble?

I saw it being used as ‘man’ in a sentence, but then some dictionary told me it was ‘male’, so I kind of got confused and wanted to ask. In English, ‘male’ and ‘man’ are kind of used differently so I wanted to know if there was such a difference in Japanese too.

ProTip:  Knowing exactly which definition applies to a kanji is often not necessary to understand the overall meaning; especially when context can help.  When you see 男 and 女 signs at the restroom, it doesn't matter if it's "Men/Women" or "Male/Female".  You know what it mean.  Of course there are times when different definitions matter, like knowing that 辛 on a menu means "spicy" as opposed to "painful/cruel/difficult".  But even then, you can see the definitions somewhat overlap to help you understand the overall meaning.

Yeah, but I for example don’t want to write ‘that male is something something’ rather than ‘that man is something something’ cause the first one is kind of offensive. I don’t know if this difference applies to Japanese though.

As a rule of thumb, it's wise to assume your knowledge of what is polite or correct in English won't be helpful in Japanese, and to assume you need to learn new frameworks. There are many ways to say "man" or "male" in Japanese, and 男 would probably not be recommended for use in a typical sentence uttered in conversation for a beginner. 男性 or 男の人 would be safer.

This question is far too vague to get a meaningful answer. What are you looking for specifically? 男 as a kanji? だん/なん as a Sino-Japanese affix? おとこ as a native Japanese word? お as a native Japanese affix?

男, as an ideographic compound kanji, is composed of two elements: 田 "rice paddy" and 力 "strength". In this regard, the "more correct" meaning would be "adult man", a man who can work on the rice paddy with his strength.

だん/なん, as a Sino-Japanese affix, can mean anything including "male human", "adult man", "son" (child or adult), "baron" (an ancient Chinese nobility title). It's different from ゆう (雄), which is used for male animals. 男子 (だんし) can mean "male child", "son" or even "adult man", and in compounds like 男子高校生, simply "male".

おとこ, as a native Japanese word, can mean lots of things. Historically, it referred to a "young boy", in contrast with おとめ, "young girl". It can be used for "adult man" by itself, but in expressions like 男の子, it can refer to  "teenage boy". Whichever is "more correct" is context-sensitive.

お, as a native Japanese affix, simply means "male" or "masculine". 男神 (おがみ) is a "male god" compared to 女神 (めがみ) "goddess". 男々しい (おおしい) is "masculine" compared to 女々しい (めめしい) "feminine". The kanji spelling matters too. If お is spelt as 男, the "more correct" meaning isn't just "male", but specifically "male human", as opposed to 雄 for "male animal".


Update: The asker says they're a beginner, and while I'm no expert myself, here are some tricks I think could be helpful:

If you're on a Japanese website (any site, not just this site), make sure to be specific. Asking a question like "what does 男 mean?" is borderline meaningless. That might be appropriate for a Chinese website, but for a Japanese one, there's a disconnect between the kanji (男) and the word itself (in this case, presumably おとこ). So ask "what does 男 (おとこ) mean?" instead.
Words can mean a lot of things depending on context. This is true for any language, not just Japanese. On english.stackexchange, an example sentence is often required. So make sure to provide context.
Don't just assume that words can only mean one thing or another only because of their English translations, which are often woefully inadequate. Thinking in English, or any European language for that matter, limits you to the mindset that there must be a difference between "male" and "man", even though oftentimes there may not be any at all.


I’m honestly too much of a beginner to consider all that, and was just searching for the meaning of the kanji when used by itself and without other kanji. Thank you for your answer.

@CoffeeSleepy For looking up kanji meanings, I often use Jisho (jisho.org), where you can add "#kanji" to the end of your search to see the various meanings of the kanji itself. Wiktionary (en.wiktionary.org) is also helpful, specifically the "Kanji" sections that precede the list of definitions proper.

@JoshGrosso thank you very much for the info. Much appreciated!
